# How to change the device that's connected with Flutter Inspector to another device on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, inspector

I'm developing a flutter app using Android Studio, and I'm running this app in 2 emulators.
After debugging the app with Flutter Inspector on the first device, I wanted to switch to the second device to debug the app on it, but I didn't find how to change the device in the Flutter Inspector window.

Note that I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose which device you wanna inspect, then click on the button "Open Flutter DevTools":

[image]

And this is the Flutter inspector opened in a Google Chrome Tab:

[image]